# Cubic 3-folds/genus 4 curves as an example of Kähler-Einstein moduli?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, moduli-spaces, kahler-einstein-metric

Is it currently known whether or not any the standard ball quotient models (As introduced in [Allcock-Carlson-Toledo](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a121/6315a6d07aa876b5155cef8a308cd9886360.pdf), [Laza](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3256), [Yokoyoma](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tjm/1244208939),... is an example of a moduli space of K-polystable Fano varieties (or equivalently - arising from the theory of Fano varieties equipped with a Kähler-Einstein metric)?

In fact - when $dim=2$, there is the [Odaka-Spotti-Sun](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.0858) moduli of Del-Pezzo surfaces. 
What is an example of a moduli space of K-polystable Fano varieties of dimension >2 that we understand explicitly?

Comment: Do we know of *any* Fano hypersurface of degree $d\geq 3$ that is proved to be $K$-stable?

Comment: I don't know ... that's why I'm asking :-) , this moduli spaces were conjectures to be such examples a few years ago ... I was wondering if that conjecture was proven.

Comment: For cubic 3-fold, see my paper with C. Xu: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1562033045